# ページスタックを自作する方法

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

トップページをAとして
A → B → C
という遷移と
A → X → Y
という遷移があります。
それぞれはpushPage()とpopPage()で行き来できます。

今回、CからYに遷移させたいのですが、その際の戻る操作は以下のように遷移させたいのです。
しかしその方法がわかりません。
C →　Y　→　X　→　A(TOP)

ページスタックを自作するなど方法はありますでしょうか？AngularJSによらない方法だと助かります。
（※CからTOPに戻れば解決する話ではありますが…）

Answer (score 0):

`ページC`から`ページY`に遷移した場合、ページスタックの`ページB`と`ページC`を削除し、`ページX`を挿入すれば実現できます。

`ons-navigator`のドキュメントも参照してください。
https://ja.onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-navigator.html

```
ons.ready(function() {
  document.querySelector("#navigator").addEventListener("postpush", function(e) {
    // page-cからpage-yに遷移したか？
    if ((e.leavePage.name == "page-c.html") && (e.enterPage.name == "page-y.html")) {
      var navi = e.navigator;
      // スタックに4ページ存在するか？
      if (navi.pages.length == 4) {
        // ページCを削除
        navi.pages[2].remove();
        // ページBを削除
        navi.pages[1].remove();
        // ページXを挿入
        navi.insertPage(1, "page-x.html");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なるほど、onsenuiの作法がまだ分かっておらず、提示いただいたコードでなんとなくやり方が見えてきました。